# Bool in touchesBegan resulting in NSInvalidArguementException crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, boolean, sprite-kit

I can't seem to workout what is wrong with the code below.
I get the following error with the BOOL isStarted:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GameScene isStarted]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc568e26680

This occurs on touching the screen first time. Once the if statement is removed, the app works correctly.

```
@interface SKScene ()
@property BOOL isStarted;
@end

...
...

-(void)start
{
self.isStarted = YES;
[hero start];
}

...

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (!self.isStarted){
   [self start];
}
else
{
    [hero jump]
}
```

[hero start] Code as follows:

```
-(void)start
{
SKAction *incrementRight = [SKAction moveByX:1.0 y:0 duration:0.03];
SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction repeatActionForever:incrementRight];
[self runAction:moveRight];

}
```

Comment: Which line does it crash on?  Your code for the if statement looks incorrect.  First it uses `isStarted` instead of `self.isStarted` or `_isStarted`, so I am surprised that it compiles.  Secondly it is an assignment `=`, not a comparison `==`

Comment: Which line is it crashing on?  Set an exception breakpoint

Comment: @Paulw11  I have re-edited code, sorry I couldn't access my Xcode to check the code I had written when I was asking this question, all should be correct now. Still crashing with error

Comment: @Paulw11 on the if statement: [GameScene isStarted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff0dac21410
2014-12-14 23:08:01.272 AppTesting [4310:1106840] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GameScene isStarted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff0dac21410'

Comment: Could it be that `@interface SKScene ()` should be `@interface GameScene ()`?

Comment: @fguchelaar your comment was correct my friend, thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `touchesBegan` instead of `UIGestureRecognizer`? A `UITapGestureRecognizer` would get the job done quite easily here.

Comment: @JaredH `touchesBegan` is a more SpriteKit-friendly approach to handling user touches. `UIGestureRecognizer`s need to be manually removed from the view when you transition scenes.